# Facebook access_token problem

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

I use a request dialog in my app where the user can send requests to their friends. Once the user sends the request i redirect the app to a page where it posts on the users page. I use the below code to get an access_token:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.APP_ID.'&client_secret='.APP_SECRET.'&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/pages/Cosmetics/167231286678063?sk=app_233227910028874&grant_type=client_credentials');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

$token = curl_exec($ch);

$me = $facebook->api('/me?'.$token);
```

but when I try to post on the wall it shows this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use PHP SDK 3.0.1 ?

Its easy if you use the sdk provided by facebook, here's the sample for authentication using php sdk 3.0.1:

```
<?php

// Requires Facebook PHP SDK 3.0.1: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/
require ('facebook.php');

define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID',"YOUR-APP-ID-HERE");
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET',"YOUR-APP-API-SECRET-HERE");
define('REDIRECT_URI',"YOUR-REDIRECT-URL-HERE");
define('PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED', "publish_stream,user_photos");
$user = null;

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser(); // Get the UID of the connected user, or 0 if the Facebook user is not connected.

if($user == 0) {
    // If the user is not connected to your application, redirect the user to authentication page
    /**
     * Get a Login URL for use with redirects. By default, full page redirect is
     * assumed. If you are using the generated URL with a window.open() call in
     * JavaScript, you can pass in display=popup as part of the $params.
     * 
     * The parameters:
     * - redirect_uri: the url to go to after a successful login
     * - scope: comma separated list of requested extended perms
     */

    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,'scope' => PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED));

    echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");

} else {
    // if the user is already connected, then fetch access_token and user's information or show some content to logged in user.
    try
    {
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); // Gives you current user's access_token

        $user = $facebook->api('/me'); // Gets User's information based on permissions the user has granted to your application.

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        $results = $e->getResult();
        // Print results if you want to debug.
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure on how exactly you are trying to authenticate.. It might be ok doing a request that way, but the method I use is the one documented here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

That is, you first redirect the user to a Facebook page in order to make him accept permissions. Once he accepts, he gets redirected to an URL you provided, with a `code=###` get argument you need to perform a server-side request in order to get the real access_token you need..

Example redirect url:

```
$my_url = 'http://www.example.com';
"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $app_id ."&redirect_uri=". urlencode($my_url);
```

Then, when the user clicks on Accept, he gets redirected to, for example

```
http://www.example.com?code=ABCDEF
```

Then, on the server-side, you need to get the access_token making a call like this:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;
```

Then double check the returned text from that call, and try getting

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=". $access_token;
```

(You can also check this by hand)

**EDIT**

Also, you probably need some more permissions from the user in order to publishi on his stream. So, ask for permissions adding a `scope=publish_stream` get to the first (user authorization) URL.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `&grant_type=client_credentials` which gives you an access token for your app as a whole, not for your current user. To get an access token for your current user you need to redirect them to the same url, but without the `&grant_type=client_credentials` and then Facebook will redirect them back to your `redirect_uri` and send along the access_token you need. Alternatively you can use the Javascript SDK to obtain an access token through a pop up window without redirecting them.

Here's a link to another question for how to authenticate with the JS SDK and no redirect: [Facebook Authentication Without Redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771569/facebook-authentication-without-redirect/6771643#6771643)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there is getting the [application access token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin):

> App Login allows you to take various administrative actions for your
>   app, such as retrieving Insights data or approving Requests. Graph API
>   calls that require an app access token are clearly denoted in the API
>   reference.

What you need is a [user access token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#server-side-flow) with some [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/), in your case it would be `publish_stream`.